3D Inverse Fourier Transform
I am trying to prove the following:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(kt)}{k} e^{i \vec k . \vec x}  d^3 k = 2\pi^2 \times \frac{\delta (t- |x|)}{|x|}$$
where $ \vec k = k_x \hat x + k_y \hat y + k_z \hat z$ , $k = \sqrt{ k_x^2 + k_y^2 +k_z^2}$ and $ \vec x$ is just the position vector.
I am unable to figure out how to approach this. Any help is appreciated.

Without loss of generality, for such a spherical problem one may set the direction of $\vec k = r e_3, z=\cos \theta $, yielding using exponentials for $\sin$
$$\int_0^{2 \pi }  \, d\phi  \ \int _0^{\infty }\frac{ \sin (r t) }{r}     \int_{-1}^1 e^{i\  r \  x \  z} \, dz  \ r^2 \ dr$$ $$=\frac{\pi}{x}  \ \int_0^{\infty } \left(-e^{-i\  r \ ( t- x)}+e^{i \ r \ (t- x)}+e^{i \ r \ (x- t)}-e^{i \  r \ ( t+ x)}\right) \, dr$$

Thanks!. However, evaluating the integral in the last line gives me some $sin[k(t-x)]$ and $sin[k(t+x)]$ terms which seem to blow up at k equals infinity. How can I deal with that?

This kind of linear functionals are limits of analytical functions along the boundary. They are determined eg  by $$\lim_{\alpha\to 0} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{- i \ k \ x  - \alpha x^2}$$ yileding the Fourier duality of $1\leftrightarrow \delta$

The Fourier transform is a tempered distribution here, not the integral of an $L^1$ function. See my post for a rigorous way forward. :-)

Two hints
$\textbf{Hint:}$
$$\frac{\delta(t-|x|)}{|x|} = \frac{\delta(t-|x|)}{t}$$
and
$\textbf{Hint:}$ It is usually easier to prove that the Fourier transform of your delta is equal to the whatever is inside of your integrand. Work the other way.
Can you take it from here?

Well, the Dirac Delta is not a function and the Fourier Transform is a tempered distribution here, not the integral of an $L^1$ function.  I've posted a rigorous solution herein.  :-)

I thought it might be instructive to present an approach that is rigorous and rooted in distribution theory.  To that end, we proceed.
We let $\psi(k;t)=\frac{\sin(kt)}{k}$ and $\phi \in \mathbb{S}$.  Without loss of generality, we assume that $t>0$.  Then, we have
$$\begin{align}
\langle \mathscr{F}\{\psi\},\phi \rangle&=\langle \psi,\mathscr{F}\{\phi\}\rangle\tag1\\\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R^3}} \frac{\sin(kt)}{k} \int_{\mathbb{R^3}} \phi(\vec r)e^{i\vec k\cdot \vec r}\,d^3r\,d^3k\tag2\\\\
&=\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R^3}}\phi(\vec r)  \int_{|\vec k|\le L} \frac{\sin(kt)}{k}e^{i\vec k\cdot \vec r}\,d^3k\,d^3r\tag3\\\\
&=\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R^3}}\phi(\vec r)  \int_0^L k^2\frac{\sin(kt)}{k}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi e^{ikr\cos(\gamma)}\,\sin(\gamma)\,d\gamma\,d\phi\,dk\,d^3r\tag4\\\\
&=\lim_{L\to \infty}8\pi\int_{\mathbb{R^3}}\frac{\phi(\vec r)}r  \int_0^L \sin(kt)\sin(kr)\,dk\,d^3r\tag5\\\\
&=\lim_{L\to \infty}4\pi\int_{\mathbb{R^3}}\frac{\phi(\vec r)}{r}\left(\frac{\sin(L(r-t))}{r-t}-\frac{\sin(L(r+t))}{r+t}\right)\,d^3r\tag6\\\\
&=\lim_{L\to \infty}4\pi\int_{\mathbb{R^3}}\frac{\phi(\vec r)}{r}\frac{\sin(L(r-t))}{r-t}\,d^3r\tag7\\\\
&=\lim_{L\to \infty}4\pi\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \int_{0}^\infty(t+r/L)\phi(t+r/L,\theta,\phi)\frac{\sin(r)}{r}\,\sin(\theta)\,d\theta\,d\phi\,dr\tag8\\\\
&=2\pi^2 \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi t\phi(t,\theta,\phi)\,\sin(\theta)\,d\theta\,d\phi\tag9
\end{align}
$$
Thus, in distribution we see that
$$\mathscr{F}\{\psi\}(\vec r)=2\pi^2\frac{\delta(r-t)}{t}$$
since we have
$$\int_{\mathbb{R^3}} 2\pi^2\frac{\delta(r-t)}{t}\phi(r,\theta,\phi)\,r^2\,\sin(\theta)\,dr\,d\theta\,d\phi=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi 2\pi^2 t\phi(t,\theta\,\phi)\,\sin(\theta)\,d\theta\,d\phi$$


NOTES:
In going from $(1)$ to $(2)$, we used the definition of the $\psi$ in the inner integral over $k$-space and defined the Fourier transform of a Schwartz function as $\int_{\mathbb{R^3}}\phi(\vec r)e^{i\vec k\cdot \vec r}\,d^3$.
In going from $(2)$ to $(3)$, we applied Fubini's theorem for interchanging the order of the integrals.
In going from $(3)$ to $(4)$, we used spherical coodinated in $k$-space and rotated the coordinate system so that $\vec r$ aligns with the polar axis in $k$-space.
In going from $(4)$ to $(5)$, we carried out the angular integrals over the solid angle in $k$-space.
In going from $(5)$ to $(6)$, we carried out the integral over $k$
In going from $(6)$ to $(7)$, we applied the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma to the second integral since $r+t>0$ and thus $\frac1{r+t}$ is well-behaved (i.e., non-singular for all $r\ge 0$.
In going from $(7)$ to $(8)$, we enforced the substitution $\vec r\mapsto \hat r t+\vec r/L$.  Then we used spherical coordinated in the transformed system
Finally, in going from $(8)$ to $(9)$, we applied the Dominated Convergence Theorem to bring the limit under the integral and carried out the radial integral.


ALTERNATIVE DEVELOPMENT
Alternatively, we can verify directly that the three-dimensional inverse Fourier transform of the distribution $2\pi^2 \frac{\delta(r-t)}{t}$ is given by $\frac{\sin(kt)}{k}$. Let $\Psi(\vec r)=2\pi^2\frac{\delta(r-t)}{t}$.  Then, we have
$$\begin{align}
\langle \mathscr{F^{-1}}\{\Psi\},\phi \rangle&=\langle \Psi,\mathscr{F^{-1}}\{\phi\} \rangle\\\\
&=\frac{1}{8\pi^3}\int_{\mathbb{R^3}}\phi(\vec k) \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi 2\pi^2 te^{-itk\cos(\theta)}\sin(\theta)\,d\theta\,d\phi\,d^3k\\\\
&=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R^3}}\phi(\vec k) 2\pi \int_0^\pi  te^{-itk\cos(\theta)}\sin(\theta)\,d\theta\,d^3k\\\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R^3}}\phi(\vec k) \frac{\sin(kt)}{k}\,d^3k
\end{align}$$
Hence, we find that in distribution
$$\mathscr{F^{-1}}\{\Psi\}(\vec k)=\frac{\sin(kt)}{k}$$
as was to be shown!
